# str_replace not working properly

Tags: php, variables, str-replace

I was experimenting with str_replace but I'm having some problems with this specific line:

```
$content = str_replace('<div id='demo'><a href='https://www.example.com' target='_blank'><img alt='Demo' src='//example.com/image.png' /></a></div>', '', $content);
```

I've tried changing the quotes but nothing worked.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I got it to work by separing the code into two different str_replace.

Comment: Your first argument is not a valid string. You cannot have unescaped quotes within quotes. Either put  \ in front of all the single quotes, or enclose the entire string in double quotes instead.

Comment: As you can see from the syntax highlighter, you need to escape your single quotes in your single quotes, or use double quotes around it.

Comment: P.S. You might want to look into a DOM parser if you're going to be doing a lot of this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with single and double quotes when you have a string

```
$content = str_replace('<div id="demo"><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Demo" src="//example.com/image.png" /></a></div>', '', $content);
```

Comment: That code doesn't give any error, but it's not removing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes, or use double quotes like this:

```
$content = str_replace("<div id='demo'><a href='https://www.example.com' target='_blank'><img alt='Demo' src='//example.com/image.png' /></a></div>", '', $content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape all single quotes, like this:

```
    $content = str_replace(
        '<div id=\'demo\'><a href=\'https://www.example.com\' target=\'_blank\'><img alt=\'Demo\' src=\'//example.com/image.png\' /></a></div>', '', $content
    );
```

Comment: That code doesn't give any error, but it's not removing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First you should define the variable $content at your code

```
  $content = str_replace('<div id='demo'><a href='https://www.example.com' target='_blank'><img alt='Demo' src='//example.com/image.png' /></a></div>', '', $content);
```

$content will refer to what?

I will give you this suggestion :

```
 <?php

 $string='<div id="demo"><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Demo" src="//example.com/image.png" /></a></div>something';
 $removed='<div id="demo"><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Demo" src="//example.com/image.png" /></a></div>';

 $content = str_replace($removed , '', $string);


 echo $content;// output something
 ?>
```